# Headset plugged into Yamaha piano and Laptop at same time. Does not have to be wireless

Tags: sound-design, sound

What audio cord/jacks do I need to enable use of Digital piano and lap top to 1 headset-does not have to be wireless right now

Answer (score 0):

You might need to source a headphone mixer in order to achieve this. It will have two inputs and one output with varying input level controls to manage the balance between the two.